# pyarrow table to parquet conversion changing blank space into ''

Tags: python, pandas, null, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to convert the pyarrow table to a parquet file.
during this conversion null values of string fields in the table are converted to '' (blank)
I want to keep it as null only.

expected :

[image]

what I am getting right now:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out to use null value instead of empty string ''. you need to use np.nan.
you need to replace empty string with np.nan in dataframe
like below example :

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

after this convert dataframe to pyarrow table and then save it as parquet file